# How to filter data with Spring Jpa over optional fields?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a method using Jpa to fetch data (in this case it is Page object). (I am using MySQL)

```
public AdvertSearchResponseDto findAdvertSearchAsPage(AdvertSearchPageRequestDto dto, Pageable pageable) throws CityNotFoundException {

        Page<AdvertSearch> advertSearchPage;
        if (dto.getCityId() != null) {
            Cities city = citiesRepository.findById(dto.getCityId())
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new CityNotFoundException(CITY_NOT_FOUND_MSG));
            if (dto.getType() != null) {
                advertSearchPage = advertSearchRepository.findByCityAndOfficeType(city.getName(), dto.getType(), pageable);
            } else {
                advertSearchPage = advertSearchRepository.findByCity(city.getName(), pageable);
            }
        } else {
            if (dto.getType() != null) {
                advertSearchPage = advertSearchRepository.findByOfficeType(dto.getType(), pageable);
            } else {
                advertSearchPage = advertSearchRepository.findAll(pageable);
            }
        }
```

As you see I get a dto as parameter and it is an object as follows:

```
@Data
public class AdvertSearchPageRequestDto {
    private Integer cityId;
    private OfficeType type;
}
```

Here is only 2 fields and I use 4 different if-else combination, but I need to add more fields to dto object and my query should work for maybe 4-5 fields so I cannot make all combinations for each fields. These fields are all optional and I need to make query for only non-null fields and It will return page so should use **Pageable**.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Using something like this:

```
@Query("select a from AdvertSearch a where (?1 is null or a.city.id = ?1) and (?2 is null or a.type = ?2)")
Page<AdvertSearch> find(Integer cityId, OfficeType type, Pageable pageable);
```